# Redundant superclass in ontology after reasoning (owlready)

Tags: python, inheritance, owl, taxonomy, owlready

I try to understand the [rector-normalization-technique](https://douroucouli.wordpress.com/2019/06/29/ontotip-learn-the-rector-normalization-technique/) for ontologies in detail. I use [owlready](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to implement the examples.

The article recommends to have a asserted single inheritance structure and introduce multiple inheritance by inference. As example it uses classes as `Protein`, `Insulin`, and `Protein_Hormone`, `Hormone_Role`.

Asserted facts:

- `Insulin` `is_subclass_of` `Protein`
- `Insulin` `plays_role` `Hormone_Role`
- `Protein_Hormone` is equivalent to (`Protein` `and` `plays_role` `owl:someValuesFrom` `Hormone_Role`) (defined class)

After the reasoner ran, `Insulin` is correctly recognized as subclass of `Protein_Hormone`    (expected result).

**However**, it is *still* classified as *direct* subclass of protein. This relation I deem redundant because every instance of `Protein_Hormone` must be a `Protein` by definition. Also, if I apply Protegé, the inferred class structure does not contain this redundant relation, as shown here:

[image: protegé export]

Is there a (canonical) way to get rid of this superfluous subclass relation?

Alternatively, why is my suspicion of superfluousness wrong?

Code for this problem (see also [this notebook](https://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/cknoll/demo-material/blob/main/expertise_system/rector-normalization-minimal.ipynb) for outputs):

```py
import owlready2 as owl2

# rme: rector-modularization-example
onto = owl2.get_ontology("https://w3id.org/yet/undefined/rme#")

with onto:

    class Protein(owl2.Thing):
        pass

    class Insulin(Protein):
        pass

    class Hormone_Role(owl2.Thing):
        pass

    class plays_role(owl2.ObjectProperty):
        pass


    class Protein_Hormone(owl2.Thing):
        equivalent_to = [Protein & plays_role.some(Hormone_Role)]

Insulin.is_a.append(plays_role.some(Hormone_Role))

# before reasoning
print(list(Protein.subclasses()))

owl2.sync_reasoner_hermit(infer_property_values=True, debug=1)

# after reasoning
print(list(Protein.subclasses()))
```